# Magento 2 - Validate product for sales rule condition

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have the sales rules collection in a helper file got the rules collection from this bit of code. Now I want to validate if the product id needs to validate against sales rule.

Constructor contains this

```
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
$this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
```

and the public function contains this

```
$_rules = $this->ruleFactory->create()->getCollection();
foreach($_rules as $rule){
            $fromDate = $rule->getFromDate();
            $toDate = $rule->getToDate();
            if (isset($fromDate) && $_currentTime >= strtotime($fromDate)) {
                if (isset($toDate)) {
                    if (strtotime($toDate) >= $_currentTime) {
                        print_r($products_id);
                        print_r($rule->getData());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Can any one help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution on this below is the way I did and it worked.

```
$products_id = $id;
    $_rules = $this->ruleFactory->create()->getCollection();

    $_currentTime = strtotime($this->datetime->date());
    $objectManager = $this->_objectManager;

    $html = " ";
    foreach($_rules as $rule){
        $fromDate = $rule->getFromDate();
        $toDate = $rule->getToDate();
        if (isset($fromDate) && $_currentTime >= strtotime($fromDate)) {
            if (isset($toDate)) {
                if (strtotime($toDate) >= $_currentTime) {
                    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($products_id);
                    $item = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
                    $item->setProduct($product);
                    //Return True if Sales Rule validate product
                    $validate = $rule->getActions()->validate($item);
                    if($validate){
                        if($rule->getId()=='8') $html .= '<span class="coupon-label"><span>'.$rule->getName().'</span></span>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It will not always work, as it is checking the entire quote Item, Once you set the condition with subselect it will fail :)

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
protected $quoteRepository;
protected $ruleData;

public function __construct(
    ...................................................................
    \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomRuleDataFactory $quoteRepository,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $ruleData,
    ...................................................................
) {
    ...................................................................
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->ruleData = $ruleData;
    ...................................................................
}

public function execute()
{
    $address = 0;
    $quotesVal = 15
    $quotesData = $this->quoteRepository->get($quotesVal);
    $customerId = (int) $quotesData->getCustomerId();
    $productCount = 0;
    foreach ($quotesData->getAllItems() as $quotesDataKey => $quotesDataVal) {
        $address = $quotesDataVal->getAddress();
        $productCount++;
        break;
    }
    if ($productCount) {
        $address->setCachedItemsAll($quotesData->getAllItems());
        $cartRuleData = $this->ruleData->create()->getCollection();
        foreach ($cartRuleData as $ruleKey => $ruleVal) {
            if ($ruleVal->getConditions()->validate($address)){ // if ($ruleVal->getActions()->validate($address))
                echo "Rule Applied";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***